# How to design toolbar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-xml, ui-design

I created a XML layout for toolbar and changed style to no action bar.
But I have 2 problems with that toolbar

1. textview in toolbar is disappear
2. toolbar has margin start and this is not match parent
   So how should I solve these problems?
   This is toolbar XML:

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:elevation="16dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            tools:text="@string/app_name" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
   ```

This is main activity XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the image of Design view in android studio

[image]

This is a picture of application in emulator

[image]

As you can see there is a problem with Texview in fragments too, its position is not correct and textview in toolbar is disappear
So How should I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your issue is `tools:text="@string/app_name"` and as mentioned in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes)

> Android Studio supports a variety of XML attributes in the tools namespace that enable design-time features (such as which layout to show in a fragment) or compile-time behaviors (such as which shrinking mode to apply to your XML resources). When you build your app, the build tools remove these attributes so there is no effect on your APK size or runtime behavior.

Any `toolsNs` attributes are removed from the XML while building the app and in your case that's why you arent seeing any text, instead use `androidNs`

so try the following in your `textview`

```
android:text="@string/app_name"
```

Comment: OMG!!! I didn't see that, this is for the first time that I use android studio templates. Thanks a lot. What about the other problem, why does not toolbar in center? What should I do for that?

Comment: Your second problem isn't clear to me, mind rephrasing it?you wanna position it in centre? Isn't it already in center?

Comment: Yes, it must be in center. You can see the XML code. But it is not in center. It seems, it has margin end. But it doesn't have any margin

Comment: Your xml seems to be alright, try to rebuild the project and see if it works else try asking the same as a new question on SO, happy coding :)